# How can I compare each element of one Char array to all element of this Char array in c#?

Tags: c#

How can I compare each element of one Char array to all element of this Char array?

I want to select one element from the array and compare to each element of this array.
my array is: Char[,] Chars = new char[81, 4];
 for Example

```
Chars[0,0] compare to Chars[1,0]
 Chars[0,0] compare Chars[1,1]
 Chars[0,0] compare Chars[1,2]
 Chars[0,0] compare Chars[1,3]
.
.
..
 Chars[0,1] compare Chars[1,0]
 Chars[0,1] compare Chars[1,1]
 Chars[0,1] compare Chars[1,2]
 Chars[0,1] compare Chars[1,3]
```

.
.
.

Comment: What do you want to do in the compare? I mean you want to find duplicates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var lengthX = Chars.GetLength(0);
var lengthY = Chars.GetLength(1)

for (int x = 0; x < lengthX; x ++) {
    for (int y = 0; y < lengthY; y ++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < lengthX; i ++) {
             for (int j = 0; j < lengthY; j ++) {
               //Your code to compare Chars[x,y] to Chars[i,j]
      }
    }
  }
}
```